# Ajax request don't return all the JSON - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, json

Well, I'm doing a AJAX request to get JSON data from a MySql database in a local server running a Flask application. I know that all my background stuff is working because when I try to access the URL that gives me all my JSON data, it works and I can see all my JSON there.

The length of the data is around 2000 items

This is the measure of 1 item:

> {
>         "col1": "2014-02-18", 
>         "col2": "{\"Data\": {\"Message Types\": {\"txt4\": {\"TotalF\": 0, \"TotalS\": 1}, \"Totals\": {\"Failure\": 2, \"Success\": 7}, \"txt1\": {\"TotalF\": 0, \"TotalS\": 2}, \"txt2\": {\"TotalF\": 0, \"TotalS\": 2}, \"txt3\": {\"TotalF\": 2, \"TotalS\": 2}}}}", 
>         "col3": "{\"717\": {\"Log\": {\"msg_medium\": \"txt3\", \"msg_content\": \"Use Climote. Save Money. Login today!\", \"state\": \"Success\", \"message_sent\": 1, \"running_state\": \"Success\"}}, \"1469\": {\"Log\": {\"msg_medium\": \"txt1\", \"msg_content\": \"Do you know engaging with Climote can lower your heating bills?\", \"state\": \"Success\", \"message_sent\": 0, \"running_state\": \"Success\"}}, \"3736\": {\"Log\": {\"msg_medium\": \"txt3\", \"msg_content\": \"Use Climote. Save Money. Login today!\", \"state\": \"Success\", \"message_sent\": 0, \"running_state\": \"Success\"}}, \"102\": {\"Log\": {\"msg_medium\": \"txt3\", \"msg_content\": \"Use Climote. Save Money. Login today!\", \"state\": \"Success\", \"message_sent\": 0, \"running_state\": \"Success\"}}, \"297\": {\"Log\": {\"msg_medium\": \"txt3\", \"msg_content\": \"Use Climote. Save Money. Login today!\", \"state\": \"Success\", \"message_sent\": 1, \"running_state\": \"Success\"}}, \"139\": {\"Log\": {\"msg_medium\": \"txt2\", \"msg_content\": \"Did you know 3 neighbours use Climote less or the same as you, 0 use it more?\", \"state\": \"Success\", \"message_sent\": 0, \"running_state\": \"Success\"}}, \"398\": {\"Log\": {\"msg_medium\": \"txt3\", \"msg_content\": \"Use Climote. Save Money. Login today!\", \"state\": \"Failure\", \"message_sent\": 1, \"running_state\": \"Failure\"}}, \"85\": {\"Log\": {\"msg_medium\": \"txt3\", \"msg_content\": \"Use Climote. Save Money. Login today!\", \"state\": \"Success\", \"message_sent\": 1, \"running_state\": \"Success\"}}, \"291\": {\"Log\": {\"msg_medium\": \"txt2\", \"msg_content\": \"Did you know 2 neighbours use Climote less or the same as you, 1 uses it more?\", \"state\": \"Success\", \"message_sent\": 0, \"running_state\": \"Success\"}}}", 
>         "col4": "{\"txt4\": 0, \"txt1\": 2, \"txt2\": 2, \"txt3\": 5}"
>       }

I'm making the requests over and over, and somehow the data returned is increasing I believe it's because of the cache of the browser... in the first time returned 33 itens, then 66, 99 ... right now is 495 =/

In Developer Tools of the chrome browser I got an error:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)"

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <!--Load JQuery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON( "http://127.0.0.1:53000/get_json", function(data) {
            var list_results = [];
            list_results = data.results
            console.log(list_results.length);
            console.log(data);

            myLiteralObj = {
               cols: [],
               rows: []
             };

             myLiteralObj.cols.push({id: 'Date', label: 'Date', type: 'date'},
                              {id: 'SuccessMsgs', label: 'SuccessMsgs', type: 'number'},
                              {id: 'FailureMsgs', label: 'FailureMsgs', type: 'number'},
                              {id: 'SuccessMsg1', label: 'SuccessMsg1', type: 'number'},
                              {id: 'FailureMsg1', label: 'FailureMsg1', type: 'number'},
                              {id: 'SuccessMsg2', label: 'SuccessMsg2', type: 'number'},
                              {id: 'FailureMsg2', label: 'FailureMsg2', type: 'number'},
                              {id: 'SuccessMsg3', label: 'SuccessMsg3', type: 'number'},
                              {id: 'FailureMsg3', label: 'FailureMsg3', type: 'number'},
                              {id: 'SuccessMsg4', label: 'SuccessMsg4', type: 'number'},
                              {id: 'FailureMsg4', label: 'FailureMsg4', type: 'number'}
                            );


            for (x=0; x<list_results.length; x++) {
              var item = $.parseJSON(list_results[x].col2);
              var arrayDate = list_results[x].col1.split("-");
              var newDate = new Date(arrayDate[0],arrayDate[1]-1,arrayDate[2]);

              myLiteralObj.rows.push({c:[
                            {v: newDate}, 
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['Totals']['Success']},
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['Totals']['Failure']},
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['txt1']['TotalS']},
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['txt1']['TotalF']},
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['txt2']['TotalS']},
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['txt2']['TotalF']},
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['txt3']['TotalS']},
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['txt3']['TotalF']},
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['txt4']['TotalS']},
                            {v: item['Data']['Message Types']['txt4']['TotalF']}
                ]});
            }
            //Getting the data into the dataTable
        var dataTotal = new google.visualization.DataTable(myLiteralObj);
        console.log(dataTotal);
        //Creating first view total msgs
        var viewTotal = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTotal);
            viewTotal.setColumns([0,1,2,{calc:totalMessagesTotal, type:'number', label:'Total Messages'}]);
            console.log(viewTotal);

        function totalMessagesTotal(dataTable, rowNum) {
          return dataTable.getValue(rowNum,1) + dataTable.getValue(rowNum,2);
        }

        var optionViewTotal = {
          vAxis: {title: "Number of Messages"},
          hAxis: {title: "Date"},
          seriesType: "bars",
          series: {2: {type: "line"}},
          width: 1000,
          height: 240
        };

        var combo = new google.visualization.ComboChart($('#chart2').children('div')[0]);
        combo.draw(viewTotal, optionViewTotal);

        //Creating view msg 1
        var view1 = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTotal);
            view1.setColumns([0,3,4,{calc:totalMessages1, type:'number', label:'Total Messages'}]);
            console.log(view1);

        function totalMessages1(dataTable, rowNum) {
          return dataTable.getValue(rowNum,3) + dataTable.getValue(rowNum,4);
        }

        var combo1 = new google.visualization.ComboChart($('#chart_msg1').children('div')[0]);
        combo1.draw(view1, optionViewTotal);

        //Creating view msg 2

        var view2 = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTotal);
            view2.setColumns([0,5,6,{calc:totalMessages2, type:'number', label:'Total Messages'}]);
            console.log(view2);

        function totalMessages2(dataTable, rowNum) {
          return dataTable.getValue(rowNum,5) + dataTable.getValue(rowNum,6);
        }


        var combo2 = new google.visualization.ComboChart($('#chart_msg2').children('div')[0]);
        combo2.draw(view2, optionViewTotal);

        //Creating view msg 3

        var view3 = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTotal);
            view3.setColumns([0,7,8,{calc:totalMessages3, type:'number', label:'Total Messages'}]);
            console.log(view3);

        function totalMessages3(dataTable, rowNum) {
          return dataTable.getValue(rowNum,7) + dataTable.getValue(rowNum,8);
        }


        var combo3 = new google.visualization.ComboChart($('#chart_msg3').children('div')[0]);
        combo3.draw(view3, optionViewTotal);

        //Creating view msg 4

        var view4 = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTotal);
            view4.setColumns([0,9,10,{calc:totalMessages4, type:'number', label:'Total Messages'}]);
            console.log(view4);

        function totalMessages4(dataTable, rowNum) {
          return dataTable.getValue(rowNum,9) + dataTable.getValue(rowNum,10);
        }

        var combo4 = new google.visualization.ComboChart($('#chart_msg4').children('div')[0]);
        combo4.draw(view4, optionViewTotal);


        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data2.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data2.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data2.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':500,
                       'height':300};

        var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#chart1').children('div')[0]);
        chart2.draw(data2, options);

        //All h2 elements when clicked will toggle the next div element near them
        $('h2').click(function () {
          $(this).next('div').toggle();
        });

          });



      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="chart1">
        <h2>Behaving Customers</h2>
        <div class="charts"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="chart2">
        <h2>Overall Messages</h2>
        <div class="charts"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="chart_msg1">
        <h2>Message1</h2>
        <div class="charts"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="chart_msg2">
        <h2>Message2</h2>
        <div class="charts"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="chart_msg3">
        <h2>Message3</h2>
        <div class="charts"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="chart_msg4">
        <h2>Message4</h2>
        <div class="charts"></div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I believe it's some problem related to the size of the JSON or some limitation of my PC, browser etc...
I'm running on a MAC OS X - Version 10.9.4 - 4GB memory, on Google Chrome up to date.

Regards - if needed my server side code is here:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db_owen = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","climote_trial")
results = []


@app.route('/get_json')
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def get_json():
    c = db_owen.cursor()
    c.execute("select * from trialresults")
    jsonresult = c.fetchall()
    for x in jsonresult:
        dic = {'col1':str(x[0]),'col2':x[1],'col3':x[2],'col4':x[3]}
        results.append(dic)

    return jsonify({ 'results':results });

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('number_1.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug= True, port=53000)
```

Comment: Ow God... After more research I discover the error... is my server code, I'm not cleaning my variable that store the results when I call the database... so I was appending eternally to it. Basically I moved my variable declaration **results = []** to inside the function **get_json()** and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know python only a little bit but as far as I can see your problem is on your server implementation. You define a **global** array `results = []` and append each record each time `get_json()` is called. But you never remove an element from the arary. I guess thats not what you want to do.